# Given two Shapefiles, how to tell which one's CRS is set correctly?

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon shapefile projected in greekgrid (GGRS87_Greek_Grid)
then I open an other shapefile which is in ETRS_1989_LAEA
In ARCGIS 9.3 the two shapefiles are displayed correctly.
But if I do the same in QGIS there is a shift of the ETRS_1989_LAEA shapefile

How can I find which of them is correct?

Comment: Add a third layer that you the projection of.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use layers from the OpenLayers plugin to verify the location of your layers.